# Manage Query Rules is missing from the Admin Console

Tags: sharepoint-online, query

In the More Features section of the SP Admin Console there *used* to be Query Rules. We have some created specific to our intranet site collection. I'm a SharePoint Admin and have always managed them this way and have seen nothing stating it will be going away. Today when I went in to edit a query rule I can no longer see that option under More Features.

[image]

I've searched the SP Admin Center and the Search & Intelligence Center, it's not anywhere I can find.

Has this feature been moved elsewhere or even deprecated as a "classic" admin page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click **Open** under **Search** in the screenshot page. Then you will find the access of Manage Query Rules.
[image]